# How to insert data into a nested multimap/map?

Tags: c++

I need to represent the data as per the following data structure. The data needs to be represented a map nested within a multimap.

```
std::multimap<int, std::map<int, double> > _model;
```

Can you please help me with an example on how to insert data in to the above model? I am not using C++ 11.

As an example, I am inserting sample data as shown below. But I am thinking the following is not a good solution.

```
        std::multimap<int, std::map<int, double> >::iterator it = _sample.find(10);
        if(it != _sample.end()) {
            std::map<int, double>& m = it->second;
            m.insert(std::pair<int, double>(10, 2.0));
        } else {
            std::map<int, double> m;
            m[10] = 20.0;

            _sample.insert(std::make_pair(10, m));
        }
```

Do you have any suggestions to improve the above version?

Comment: Side note: Don't use `_` name prefixes anywhere, not intended to be compiler intrinsic. Better: `model_` As for your question: Insert which data, when? Did you try something? Where did you fail upon  exactly?

Comment: You can insert data by calling the [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert) member function of [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap).

Comment: Can you provide an example for insert function of multimap for the above model, please?

Comment: Its an interesting data structure. Given that several `std::map`s will share the same key in the `std::multimap` how do you decide which `std::map` to insert the value into?

Comment: You seem to be inserting an entry if none is present, otherwise modifying the existing entry. That's what `map` is for; why would you use a multimap?  Also if the inner map always has the same key as the multimap then just use a single `map`.

Comment: The above code will throw an exception if called twice (since the inner map will be inserted into twice with the same key)

Comment: I think you need to explain more about what the data structure is supposed to represent.

Answer (score 0):

In the `map` the `operator[]` search for the `key` if is not present, inserted and return a `default constructed value`, if is present return the value of the key.

In the `multimap` this operator in not present because don't know what of the possible multiple value associated to the same key would return.

You could use also [`boost:assign`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html).

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/assign/std/map.hpp>

using namespace boost::assign;

int main() {
    // std version
    typedef std::map<int, double> internal_map_t;
    std::multimap<int, internal_map_t> _model;

    internal_map_t newelem;
    newelem[0] = 3.14;
    _model.insert(std::make_pair(25, newelem));

    // boost assign version
    internal_map_t newelem1;
    insert( newelem1 )( 1, 3.15 );
    insert( _model )( 26, newelem1 );        

    return 0;
}
```

One question: if you would search for an element and if exist append data to that element, why use a `multimap` and not a `map` (where you could chain call to `operator[]`).